# How to find what relations exists between 2 nodes neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, neo4jclient

Lets say i have these nodes with these relations `(A,B) are nodes` and `Rs are Relation Names`:

```
A-R1->B
A-R2->B
A-R3->B
```

Now i do not actually know if one or any `R` has relation between these 2 nodes. how can i specify if any relation exists between these 2 nodes regardless of knowing what relation is it?

Also if there are any relation exists between these two nodes is it possible to know what relation is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can i specify if any relation exists between these 2 nodes
>   regardless of knowing what relation is it?

I believe that a simple MATCH will be sufficient. The below query returns all relationships between a node named "A" and a node named "B", if exists.

```
MATCH ({name : "A"})-[r]->({name : "B"})
RETURN r
```

> Also if there are any relation exists between these two nodes is it
>   possible to know what relation is it?

The [type()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/scalar/#functions-type) function returns a string representation of the relationship type. Then the below query will return the string representing the type of each relationship between A and B.

```
MATCH ({name : "A"})-[r]->({name : "B"})
RETURN type(r) as type
```

Comment: I mostly code cypher using neo4jClient of asp.net, can i return the type of relation within neo4jClient as well?

Comment: I never used neo4jClient of asp.net, but I believe that you need simply call `type()` and will works. Has no differences between use Cypher from web browser interface and from a client library.

Comment: From `Neo4jClient` you would do it like this: `IEnumerable<string> results = gc.Cypher
   .Match("({name: 'A'})<-[r]-({name: 'B'})")
   .Return(() => Return.As<string>("type(r)"))
   .Results;`